# What is wrong - if any - with the following Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

Project Euler problem: 1
Note: GHCi implementaion: type 'main' to output result

Multiples of 3 and 5

Problem:
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
-- all multiples of 3 less than 1000
multOfThree = [3*x | x <- [1..333] ]

-- all multiples of 5 less than 1000
multOfFive = [5*x | x <- [1..199] ]

-- common values of the two lists
commonValues = [x | x <- multOfThree, x <- multOfFive]

-- list of all multiples, subtract commonValues (as there are two copies - one per list)
multiplesOfThreeOrFive = (multOfThree ++ multOfFive) -- commonValues

sumOfMultiples = sum multiplesOfThreeOrFive

-- display sum:
main = print sumOfMultiples
```

Comment: Why are you asking "if any"? Does it work as intended? Are you asking for a [codereview.se]?

Comment: Yes. A code review. My answer: 266333 is supposedly incorrect according to Project Euler.

Comment: You're counting 15 twice.

Comment: I find `(multOfThree ++ multOfFive) -- commonValues` a pretty awesome mistake. I know exactly what you wanted this to do, but `--` starts a comment. (You must know, given how many other comments you wrote, but perhaps it slipped your mind. =) The function is actually called `(\\)`. (There are other mistakes, too, though: try predicting the value of `length commonValues`, then asking ghci whether your prediction is right.)

Comment: @UGPhysics: Please note that [CodeReview.SE] is only appropriate if your code works. At the moment, it doesn't. Keep that in mind before your question gets closed there.

Comment: @DanielWagner How can I fix commonValues? (I'm new to Haskell as you might surmise.)

Comment: @DanielWagner commonValues = [x | x <- multOfThree, x <- multOfFive, ((x <- multOfThree) && (x <- multOfFive)) == True]

Comment: @DanielWagner Error message: parse error on input ‘<-’
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?

Comment: You probably want `commonValues = [ x | x <- list1 , elem x list2 ]`, i.e. "those x in list1 which are elements of list2".

Comment: @chi I want to rewrite my code using a 'do' block. How can I do that?

Comment: It depends on what you actually want to do. An example could be `main = do let x = 3; let y=4; print (x+y)`. You can start a new (indented) line instead of using semicolons. Anyway, any good tutorial should cover that stuff, try http://learnyouahaskell.com/ which seems to be quite popular nowadays.

Comment: @chi The error is above- in relation to the list comprehension that I tried writing. | I want to rewrite the code using a 'do' block instead.

Comment: @UGPhysics In the code that gives the error message, you want to use the `elem` function (you were very close): `elem x multOfThree && elem x multOfFive`. The `<-` thing is only for doing a bind, not for checking to see if something is in a list. You will also find that you need to separate names, not just `x` for both.

Comment: It should have been `commonValues = [x | x <- multOfThree, y <- multOfFive, x==y]`. Nested bindings in list comprehension shadow the outer ones (the second `x` in your code makes first `x` inaccessible;  it's a new variable with the same name, not a variable with the same value - for that we need to compare their values, with `==`). 

As for the summation, you either do

      `sum ((multOfThree ++ multOfFive) \\ commonValues)`

or

    `(sum multOfThree + sum multOfFive) - sum commonValues`

Comment: and of course, [`commonValues = [15,30..1000]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 1):

Two things do not work as you intended:

### List subtraction

To use set difference with lists, use `\\` from `Data.List`. `--` actually starts a comment.

```
import Data.List ((\\))
multiplesOfThreeOrFive = (multOfThree ++ multOfFive) \\ commonValues
```

or skip commonValues and use `Data.List.union`.

### List comprehension

```
commonValues = [x | x <- multOfThree, x <- multOfFive]
```

Unfortunately, you cannot translate the common mathematical notation and turn  that '''e''' symbol into `<-`. The reason is, it is only ''common'', not formal mathematics: The first `<-` means to iterate over the first set, the second one is a predicate (condition). You can directly write this as

```
commonValues = [x | x <- multOfThree, x `elem` multOfFive]
```

as mentioned by chi.

### Remarks

These are the things that are wrong in the sense of "produce a wrong result". In the [related code review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161439/project-euler-1-sum-of-multiples-of-3-or-5-less-than-1000-in-haskell), you will get further advice.